# IF ELSE Conditional Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bit of a puzzle which I similar to other questions but there is a slight twist.

I have a dataframe - see below. Each record is unique and some records have multiple admit locations in the `Concat` column. The `CONCAT` columns reflects the progression of a patients admissions location status.

I want to know where patients ended.

I know that if the text within the `CONCAT` column is '3E PICU' or  '6EN' or '3MN' or '6E' or '3MC' regardless of any other text that is in the column, they ended in the ICU.

I know that if a patient had any of the following admit locations with the `CONCAT` column,  **WITHOUT** any of the ICU locations they can be considered "ACUTE": '4E' or '5E NSU' or '3E HKU'(see code below for full list of locations).

I know that if a patient had APU or CPU or PSU regardless of any other location that is in the `CONCAT` column, they can be considered "Psych".

I know that if patient is not considered ICU or ACUTE or PSYCH, they were not admitted.

Current Data

```
 ID              Concat 
  1              MAIN, 3E HKU, 6EN 
  2              ED Eval and Treatment Unit
  3              ED Main, 3E PICU
  4              ED Main, APU
```

Desired Data

```
 ID              Concat                              Admit Status 
  1              MAIN, 3E HKU, 6EN                       ICU
  2              ED Eval and Treatment Unit            Non-Admit
  3              ED Main, PICU                           ICU
  4              ED Main, APU                           Psych
  5              ED Main, 5E NSU, 3E HKU                Acute
```

I am familiar with the `str.contains` code but I need some help in illogically mapping out the code, especially if if else conditions are required.

```
 condition_one=new_ADM1["concat"].str.contains("3E PICU|6EN|3MN|6E|3MC", case=False)
 condition_two=new_ADM1["concat"].str.contains("4E|5E NSU|3E HKU|3E|4MN|5E SCU|4MA|7E|7E IRU", case=False)
 condition_three=new_ADM1["concat"].str.contains("APU|CPU|PSU", case=False)
```

Comment: `np.select([condition_one,condition_two,condition_three],[value1,value2,value3])` should do

Comment: the issue with that is that ACUTE designation may still grab ICU patients because some ICU patients also have ACUTE admit locations.

Comment: `'3E PICU'`?? `ID` 3 shows ICU with only `PICU` in its string.

Comment: my mistake - I have changed it to say "3E PICU"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) along with the given `regex` patterns, then use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to select the items from choices based on the conditions `m1, m2 & m3`:

```
m1 = df["Concat"].str.contains("(?i)(?:3E PICU|6EN|3MN|6E|3MC)$")
m2 = df["Concat"].str.contains("(?i)(?:4E|5E NSU|3E HKU|3E|4MN|5E SCU|4MA|7E|7E IRU)$")
m3 = df["Concat"].str.contains("(?i)(?:APU|CPU|PSU)$")

df['Admit Status'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['ICU', 'Acute', 'Psych'], 'Non-Admit')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
   ID                      Concat Admit Status
0   1           MAIN, 3E HKU, 6EN          ICU
1   2  ED Eval and Treatment Unit    Non-Admit
2   3            ED Main, 3E PICU          ICU
3   4                ED Main, APU        Psych
```

Comment: Thanks this runs but every record in the `Admit Status` column says "Non-Admit" which is incorrect.

Comment: @Raven As per the data you have provided this should produce the correct results.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me understand what the ("(?i)(?: .......$") is instructing the code to do?

Comment: `(?i)` is case insensitive match flag which is equivalent to setting `case=False`.  `(?:)` is a non capturing group and `$` is used to indicate a position at the end of line.

Comment: would your code change if there were no commas separating the locations within the `Concat` column?